# What happens when an APK is installed on SD card?

Tags: android, installation, android-sdcard, android-package-managers, android-external-storage

Say we want to install an APK named **x.apk** to an Android phone.

By default, at least two things will happen:

1. Copy **x.apk** to `/data/app`;
2. Create a package folder under `/data/data` as the private storage space;

However, if **x.apk** is to be installed on SD card,

What are the folders corresponding to `/data/app` and `/data/data` on SD card?

Answer (score 0):

They should remain the the same path but mounted on the sdcard, for that you need rooted device I think.